# Switch Statement in Java will choose opposite case

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I'm using a switch statement in a class's method that's called by another class.

The Switch statement gets as input a variable representing an `enum` type.

Called Class:

```
public class called_foo {

    public static enum ENUM_TYPE {
        TYPE2, TYPE1
    }

    public void method( ENUM_TYPE type ){

        switch( type ){

            case TYPE1: System.out.println("TYPE1");
                        break;

            case TYPE2: System.out.println("TYPE2");
                        break;

            default:    System.out.println("Error in retrieving Type");
                        System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Calling Class:

```
public class calling_foo {

    public void run(){

        called_foo cf = new called_foo();
        cf.method( ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1 );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        calling_foo f = new calling_foo();
        f.run();
    }

}
```

First Question: "Are there any errors in the syntax of these two classes?"

Second Question: "If not, why is output the opposite of what I'm expecting?"

Output:

```
if I call cf.method( ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1 ); I see on screen "TYPE2"
if I call cf.method( ENUM_TYPE.TYPE2 ); I see on screen "TYPE1"
```

Comment: The compiler won't compile if there are syntax errors ;)

Comment: First Answer: ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1 is unknown to calling_foo. If i use the one of called_foo, it works as one would expect.

Comment: @tim `ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1` is ok I think, I have already used this syntax in other parts and it doesn't give any problems

Comment: @Pangea I can't see your answer any more, did you delete it? cause I didn't understand well it's content..

Comment: can you add TYPE3 and check output coming for `ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1`, `ENUM_TYPE.TYPE2` and `ENUM_TYPE.TYPE3`

Comment: works when I change cf.method( ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1 ); to cf.method( called_foo.ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1 );

Comment: @Apurv : When you do changes, what do you get for TYPE1?? Still o/p as TYPE2 or TYPE1

Comment: @FahimParkar I am getting TYPE1 for TYPE1 (as expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't manage to compile your code "as is". I think you have defined ENUM_TYPE another time in calling_foo, with TYPE1 and TYPE2 reversed, so that `calling_foo.ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1` is actually the one used, and correspond to `called_foo.ENUM_TYPE.TYPE2` .

You should specify that the `ENUM_TYPE` enumeration to use is actually `called_foo.ENUM_TYPE.TYPE1` when you call cf.method. This way the code does compile and you get the expected result.

Comment: you were right...I really did a stupid mistake!thks for help ;)